# How to plot gridlines through centrod of contourplot?

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

Please suggest how to plot gridlines that passes through centre of   contour plot (green line in image):

```
w0 = 1000*10^-6; l = 8; λ = 532*10^-9; rx = .004; we = 100*10^-6;
qw[r_?NumericQ, ϕ_?NumericQ] := ((r Sqrt[2])/w0)^Abs[l] 
     Exp[-r^2/w0^2] Cos[(l ϕ + .000002* Exp[-1 r^2/(100 we^2)]*(Pi/λ))]^2

ContourPlot[Evaluate[qw[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]]], {x, -rx, rx }, {y, -rx, rx},
     Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> All, 
     ImageSize -> {400, 400}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PerformanceGoal -> {"Speed", "Quality"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, a related problem that is easy to solve is to draw lines in the direction of steepest descent, since this direction is given by the gradient. We could use `NDSolve` to find those lines. For this problem, we would have to do something similar but instead of the gradient, we would need to figure out the direction of "slowest" descent. Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to get that direction other than taking small steps and minimizing the gradient as a function direction at every step, which is a bit cumbersome to implement.